# Using momentJS to get the time today at a certain string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So basically if I have a string `'8:00 PM'`, I want to get a moment object for today's date at 8PM.

Obviously, `moment('8:00 PM')` won't do it.  I've also tried to use `moment().startOf('day')`, but I'm not sure how to get it set to 8PM.  It has to be from a string or I would be able to add hours or minutes to get the time I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to parse the time with moment.

the format is `moment('your time', 'your time format')`

So for your time it would be something like below

```
moment('8:00 PM', 'h:mm A')
```

This way moment will recognize your time format. Then if you want to print it out in the same format again you can implement below

```
moment('8:00 PM', 'h:mm A').format('h:mm A')
```

Below takes a step further and formats the moment object that was parsed.

Comment: The answer is correct since [Defaults](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section of the docs states that _You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds._

Answer (score 1):

You may get what you want by this:

```
moment(`${moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')} 8:00 AM`)
```